# How to change crystal report row forecolor base on dates

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using vb.net , mysql as backend, crystal report as reporting. How can i change the row forecolor in my crystal report according to date. For example, all August 1 would be blue, August 2 would be red, august 8 would be blue and so on. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the report object (Text object) -> click Format Object. Click the Font tab. Then click the Formula Editor button to the right of the Color selection dropdown box.

I use Basic Syntax because it's closer to VB.Net

```
if Day(<name of your column>) = 1 then
    formula = crBlue
elseif Day(name of your column) = 2 then
    formula = crRed
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select all text objects in the section (or "row" as you refer to it), you can apply the logic above to all of them in one step.